# Syntax Error for Referential Triggered Actions in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a new table with "on delete" and "on update" referential triggered actions, but it keeps saying that there is a syntax error. When I tried to run the script, the error message is "missing right parentheses". I don't understand why this is not right.

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON
(SSN        VARCHAR(9)          NOT NULL,
 Name       VARCHAR(20)         NOT NULL,
 Phone      VARCHAR(10),
 Address    VARCHAR(40),
 Employer   VARCHAR(20),
 Insurer    VARCHAR(20),
 PCP        INT,
 CONSTRAINT PERPPK
  PRIMARY KEY(SSN),
 CONSTRAINT PEREMPFK
  FOREIGN KEY(Employer) REFERENCES EMPLOYER(Name)
              ON DELETE SET NULL      ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT PERINSFK
  FOREIGN KEY(Insurer) REFERENCES INSURER(Name)
              ON DELETE SET NULL      ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT PERPCP
  FOREIGN KEY(PCP) REFERENCES PHYSICIAN(PID)
              ON DELETE SET NULL      ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

Comment: the error message shows after the first on delete statement

Comment: Where in the [Oracle manual](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/toc.htm) did you find the `on update` syntax?

Answer (score 0):

`ON UPDATE CASCADE` is not valid syntax. There is no direct way to do this and for good reason. You should not be creating a model where you have to update values in Primary keys. Primary keys should only be created and dropped, never updated. If it is being updated, then it is probably not a primary key. But that is a design consideration that you would have to make.

If you want to implement something like cascading updates, you could maybe do it with a stored procedure and deferrable constraints. Defer the constraint and update both the parent and foreign keys before committing.

[Here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5773459616034) is the asktom discussion on this. [Another.](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:130261000346380506)